# Can I add multiple models from different apps to one admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Can I add multiple models from different apps to one admin site? I would like see e.g both apps (polls, news) models under one roof of admin panel.

For now in my Django admin site **NONE** of the models is displayed.

I try in admin.py file

```
from tutorial.polls.models import Poll, Choice
from tutorial.news.models import Article, Reporter
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Poll)
admin.site.register(Choice)
admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(Reporter)
```

My catalogs structure:

```
(example)andi@MacBook-Pro-Andrzej:~/example/tutorial$ ls -lR
total 8
-rw-r--r--   1 andi  staff   251B 28 paź 11:53 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  12 andi  staff   408B 31 paź 02:46 news/
drwxr-xr-x   9 andi  staff   306B 31 paź 02:46 polls/
drwxr-xr-x  12 andi  staff   408B 31 paź 03:06 tutorial/


    ./news:
    total 64
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff     0B 31 paź 00:18 __init__.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   210B 31 paź 02:09 base.html
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   466B 31 paź 01:26 models.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   383B 31 paź 00:18 tests.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   277B 31 paź 02:08 views.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   329B 31 paź 01:53 year_archive.html

    ./polls:
    total 40
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff     0B 31 paź 02:32 __init__.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   612B 31 paź 02:33 models.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   383B 31 paź 02:32 tests.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff    26B 31 paź 02:32 views.py

    ./tutorial:
    total 72
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff     0B 28 paź 11:53 __init__.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   244B 31 paź 03:06 admin.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   5,4K 31 paź 02:34 settings.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   752B 31 paź 02:36 urls.py
    -rw-r--r--  1 andi  staff   1,4K 28 paź 11:53 wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Django programming!

Easy! Create an `admin.py` in `polls/` and `news/`, and only include the models you need for that app.

For example, `polls/admin.py` might contain:

```
from models import Poll, Choice
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Poll)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

That ought to work just fine.

(I believe your current approach isn't working because `polls` and `news` aren't reachable from within `tutorial/admin.py`, and `tutorial.polls.models` can't find them -- `polls/` and `models/` would need to be subdirectories of `tutorial/` for that to work. Otherwise you're on the right track -- keep going! :) )

Comment: Thank you. I just created admin.py in each of the app. I was not expecting that django will merge it automatically, but the magic have happend.